# nth node from the end(Linked List) using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

Can anybody explain how this actually works. I am not able to understand recursion, what happens after we recursively reach to the end of the linked list and how does the unwinding takes place along with the operations(increment and if condition checking)?

[Linked List](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nth-node-from-the-end-of-a-linked-list/)

```
void printNthFromLast(struct node* head, int n) 
{
static int i = 0;
if(head == NULL)
   return;
printNthFromLast(head->next, n);
if(++i == n)
   printf("%d", head->data);
}
```

Comment: Note that the function can only be called *once*. The initialization of the variable `i` happens only in the first call to the function.

Comment: if you are able to understand any simple recursion then its simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns if the struct node* passed to it is NULL. This will happen if either the linked list has zero nodes or if we have reached the end of the linked list.

```
if(head == NULL)
    return;
```

Otherwise, each instance of the function will be waiting at this line for it's 'child' to return:

```
printNthFromLast(head->next, n);
```

No printing is done until we've reached the end of the list. Once we HAVE reached the end of the list, the final function called will return on the if statement because head == NULL, since we're at the end.

Each instance of the function will now proceed to executing these lines (once it's 'child' has returned):

```
if(++i == n)
    printf("%d", head->data);
```

It's basically counting from the back. Each instance increments i by 1 and then checks if it's equal to the number n we provided. If it is, it prints the data. Otherwise, it just ends and it's 'parent' gets a chance to execute these lines.

**Edit:** This really is a very poor way to do what you're doing. Your program could run out of stack memory if the list is reasonably large. You should do this by iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This in my opinion is such a poorly done function, but I'll try and explain how I see it.

Basically you are pushing multiple recursive functions onto a stack until you hit the base case, you're only however popping off about half the function each time, leaving the rest there to complete after the next function. When you hit the base case, no more recursion takes place and you have to go back down the stack, popping off each function until you're at the parent function and it will finish and you're done.